# SDL_image is not working

Tags: c++, c, dll, sdl

I am attempting to load a png file with SDL. I have followed all instructions. The SDL2_image.dll and the SDL2.dll are located in the same folder as the executable. As is the other dlls; libjpeg-9.dll, libpng16-16.dll, libtiff-5.dll, libwebp-7.dll, and zlib1.dll. These are all located in the some folder that contains the executable.

In the file where I call the sdl command

```
 SDL_Surface* pTempSurface = IMG_Load("assets/animate.png");
```

I include the header file #include

And in my addiditional dependencies I include the SDL2.lib, SDL2main.lib and SDL2_image.lib

However I get a popup box that reads
       "The procedure entry point SDL_LoadFile_RW could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Users[name]\source\repos[name][name]\Release\SDL2_image.dll"

What is it that I might be doing wrong

Comment: Try using [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see if that function is actually in the DLL

Comment: I know you are trying to use SDL, however I found another image loading library that works great with OpenGL, haven't tried it yet with DirectX and that is `stb_image`. It is a header's only library that supports `JPEG`, `PNG`, `TGA`, `PSD`, `BMP`, `PSD`, `GIF`, `HDR`, `PIC`, `PNM` formats. Easy to include, setup and use. You can find their library information here: https://stb.handmade.network/ and download it from here: https://github.com/nothings/stb Just some reference materials that you could look into.

Comment: `SDL_LoadFile_RW` first appeared in SDL 2.0.6; you probably have older dll.

Comment: Thanks @FrancisCugler but I am aware of stb as aimage loading library, as well as SOIL which is another good one. However this exercise is meant to be done in SDL alone.

Comment: Excellent advice @keltar. I was using an older version of SDL and SDL_image. I have since started using SDL_2.0.7 and SDL_image-2.0.2. The program compiles and renders successfully now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using an older version of SDL and SDL_image. I have since started using SDL_2.0.7 and SDL_image-2.0.2. The program compiles and renders successfully now